# how can I get top smallest tensor values based on a condition in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a tensor like this:

```
sim_topics = [[0.65 0.   0.   0.   0.42  0.   0.   0.51 0.   0.34 0.]
              [0.   0.51 0.   0.  0.52  0.   0.   0.   0.53 0.42 0.]
              [0.    0.32 0.  0.50 0.34  0.   0.   0.39 0.32 0.52 0.]
              [0.    0.23 0.37 0.   0.    0.37 0.37 0.   0.47 0.39 0.3 ]]
```

and one boolean tensor like this:

```
bool_t = [False  True  True  True]
```

I want to select part of `sim_topics` based on the bool flag in `bool_t` in a way it just select `top k smallest` values per row(if the row is true if not leave it as it is).

So the expected output would be like this:(here `k=2`)

```
[[0.65 0.   0.    0.   0.42  0.   0.   0.51 0.   0.34 0.]
 [0.   0.51 0.   0.  0.52  0.   0.   0.   0.53 0.42 0.]
 [0.   0.32 0.    0.50 0    0    0.   0.   0    0.32 0 ]
 [0.   0.23 0     0.   0.    0    0    0.   0    0    0.3 ]]
```

I was trying to accomplish this first by using `boolean_mask` and `where` to get the indices I want then go get the top smallest. However, when I use `where` it does not give me the indices where there is  `zero`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k = 2
dim0 = sim_topics.shape[0]
a = tf.cast(tf.equal(sim_topics,0), sim_topics.dtype)
b = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(a,1) + k, (dim0,-1))
c = tf.cast(tf.argsort(tf.argsort(sim_topics,1),1), sim_topics.dtype)
d = tf.logical_or(tf.less(c,b),tf.reshape(tf.logical_not(bool_t),(dim0,-1)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(sim_topics * tf.cast(d,sim_topics.dtype)))


[[0.65 0.   0.   0.   0.42 0.   0.   0.51 0.   0.34 0.  ]
 [0.   0.51 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.42 0.  ]
 [0.   0.32 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.32 0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.23 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.3 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Actually, It prints out the correct answer, though I would like to learn your approach. could you explain it how did you come up with this solution? Actually, its totally different from my mind process and I would like to learn it:)

Comment: @sariii my aim is to only get the top K smallest. Since 0 are considered as smallest, and there are no negative numbers, then, eg if there are 3 zeros and we need top 2, then we need 5 numbers, the 3 zeros and the 2 numbers. So thats why I have `b = a+k`. then `c` is the index where the value should lie in the vector. Then I only want those values in `c` that are less than `b` and need to be changed according to the `bool_t` that is `d`.

Comment: Actually there are negative numbers as well. I should have a better tensor sample:| could you let me know what thing should I change so that it can work on the negatives as well?(but I dont want to consider them as smallest, I want top positive smallest

Comment: @sariii if you want top-positive smallest, force the negative numbers to be zero, then use the code above, then include the negative numbers

Comment: That makes sense. I just was worried it might not work based on this approach. Thanks:)

Comment: I am so sorry for still spamming you on this question. For some reason I need to use tf version 1.12which as you know does not have `argsort`. I read that instead of argsort we can use `tf.nn.topk`. though Im not sure I can apply it correctly for this approach as already giving the `k` in `b` variable. could you please let me know how can I change it to work without `argsort`?

Comment: @sariii i have to look into that then get back to you

Comment: @sariii to use `top_k`, in the above code replace line `c` with `c = tf.cast(tf.nn.top_k(tf.nn.top_k(sim_topics,sim_topics.shape[1])[1][:,::-1],
                   sim_topics.shape[1])[1][:,::-1],sim_topics.dtype)`

Comment: I can not be more thankful, really appreciate your help:)

Comment: I ended up reshaping it, I did not find any elegant way to do it. Thanks.